# New RAID-5 volume is grayed out

Tags: software-raid, windows-10-v1607

I try to create a RAID5 volume with 5 disks, all 5 are exactly the same
(5x Seagate thin 250GB)

Disk Management can see every disk, also I can choose every RAID except the RAID5.

Because, I love the command line, I tried to create the volume with diskpart. But at the end it give me the error:

```
DISKPART> create volume raid size=1000000 disk=1,2,3,4,5
The command you selected is not available with this version of Windows.
```

But, why can't I create the RAID5 volume? I have a fully activated Windows 10 Enterprise version.

Comment: Use Storage Spaces. They’re just as proprietary as Dynamic Disks, but more up-to-date in terms of features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client Editions of Windows (10) don't support RAID5:

```
  <sl:policyInt name="volmgrx-SupportDynamic" attributes="reboot-required, override-only">1</sl:policyInt> 
  <sl:policyInt name="volmgrx-SupportMirror" attributes="reboot-required, override-only">1</sl:policyInt> 
  <sl:policyInt name="volmgrx-SupportRaid5" attributes="reboot-required, override-only">0</sl:policyInt>
```

As you see `volmgrx-SupportRaid5` is set to `0` in Windows 10. You need a Server OS, here it is licensed.